# Can rel="next" and rel="prev" can be ignored in blog listings

Tags: seo, duplicate-content, rel, pagination

We have a blog - which is current spread to 9 pages, every page has a unique title - page 1, page 2, page 3 and so on.

Also, as it's a blog, every page has unique 10 listing entry on one page.

Is `rel="prev"` and `rel="next"` can be safely ignored as all these are listing and not content pages of article. What I read in all through Google Search is that `rel="next"` and `rel="prev"` should be applicable on where the content is spread across multiple pages.

But - as it's a blog, it has blog listings and every listing has unique content
This is the blog: `http://www.mycarhelpline.com/index.php?option=com_easyblog&view=latest&Itemid=91`.

May recommend, if by ignoring `rel="next"` and `rel="prev"` - are we inviting Google to treat the blog listing pages as duplicate.

Answer (score 1):

http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.com/2012/03/video-about-pagination-with-relnext-and.html

Try this Official Google Help to use `rel="prev"` and `rel="next"` right.

In you situation you should use `rel="prev"` and `rel="next"` for your pagination.

Comment: Thanks, its mentioned 
In regard to using rel=”next” and rel=”prev” for entries in your blog that “are not strictly correlated (but they are just time-sequential),” pagination markup likely isn’t the best use of your time -- time-sequential pages aren’t nearly as helpful to our indexing process as semantically related content, such as pagination on component pages in an article or category. It’s fine if you include the markup on your time-sequential pages, but please note that it’s not the most helpful use case. If i interpret it correctly, rel="prev" and rel="next" markup may not be best way.

Comment: Google likes when you have "view-all" page, but if you don't have this one, you should use rel="prev" and rel="next" to help Google index it correctly.